# anaconda spyder restarts with old arguments

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, spyder

I had run some CNN code in my spyder but I interrupted that action in between after some epochs.
now when I restart my kernel, if I run any code, so it is automatically starting that old CNN code & starts training that old model.

[image: New Kernel]

[image: running new code]

[image: automatically running old code]

(sorry for my bad english)
whatever I can do, I did it, made new env, reinstalled spyder, python, tensorflow, keras but nothing working
and on same environment am using jupyter notebook & it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in spyder 4.0 they have changed by-default cell executing to **F9**

those who used spyder 3.0, they were used to execute cell with ctrl+ enter or shift+enter

u can still change it 
Tools -> Preferences - Keyboard Shortcuts

same problem people were facing here
https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/8994

Comment: i was working for my client web https://uniquefumigation.com/